# Does Reinvesting eliminate all your Hyperbits?

Tags: bitcoin-billionaire

If I were to Reinvest, would I end up without any Hyperbits, or would they still remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. It also affirms this when you click Reinvest.

More info:
https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinBillionaireApp/comments/3gm7wr/do_hyperbits_go_back_to_0_when_you_reinvest/